# No wifi adapter found Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu on my Asus G750JS, but the WiFi in not working.

Some info :

```
$ sudo lshw -class network

*-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:eda00000-eda07fff memory:ed800000-ed9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 40:16:7e:11:a1:4b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:edb00000-edb3ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20u4
       serial: 5e:7d:35:46:96:50
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.101 link=yes multicast=yes`
```

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep Network

    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2123]'
```

I tried:

```
$ sudo rfkill

ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

This doesn't make any difference:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This as well:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms`
```

Nothings works. Does anyone ever had the same problem and found a solution?
I spent hours on forums and tried different things, but nothing changes. The WiFi still doesn't work.
I obviously tried the <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> button combination.

Comment: Results for `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: I suspect that you will need to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy31 and chili555 I disable the Secure Boot and now it's working.